# Sub routes at react router 4

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I am having problems dividing my application and using several routers. I have a main router where it handles several small applications and in each mini application I want to manage its opportune routes. What am I failing?
What I want to do is when I receive the data of the request, redirect me to a new screen but I can not get it. Can anybody help me? Thank you

Example https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-c2tkgf?file=Hello.js

**Routes.js**

```
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import React from 'react'
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import { AuthenticatedRoute } from 'components/authenticated-route'
import Clients from 'components/clients'
import { Login } from 'components/login'
import Home from './Home/Home'
const Routes = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />} />
        <Route exact path="/clients" component={Clients} />
        <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}

export default Routes
```

**Clients.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import Dashboard from './Dashboard/Dashboard'
import { Redirect, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'

class Clients extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SearchCustomers />
        {this.props.customer.token ? (
          <div>
            <Switch>
              <Route path={`/clients:${this.props.customer.id}/dashboard`} component={Dashboard} />
            </Switch>
            <Redirect to={`/clients:${this.props.customer.id}/dashboard`} />
          </div>
        ) : null}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    customer: state.customer,
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Clients)
```

Comment: If you make an example [here](https://stackblitz.com/fork/react) I'll take a look for you.

Comment: One possible solution is to put a redirect in an if statement based on either the state or props... if that conditional is true... give the redirect instead of the default render.

Comment: @Colin The example! https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-c2tkgf?file=Hello.js

Comment: @jmrosdev thanks, what's the desired behavior on this example?

Comment: Is it this? https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-c2tkgf?file=Bye.js

Comment: @Colin I want that when I press the button I change the screen to the route / bye. The definition of the route has to be in the Hello component and not in the App

Comment: @jmrosdev why that limitation?

Comment: @Colin I want to divide the application into subapplications and that the component sub-routes of the component are defined in the component

Comment: any ideas? I can not think of anything else!

Answer (score 2):

In your Routes component you have:

```
<Route exact path="/clients" component={Clients} />
<Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />} />
```

since you have `exact` on there, those components will only be rendered when at exactly `/clients` or `/login`.  in your built components, once you change the path, your parent component no longer renders, therefore nothing inside those components will render.  remove the exact from your Routes:

```
<Rout path="/clients" component={Clients} />
<Rout path="/login" component={Login} />} />
```

Comment: I've tried what you propose but it does not work, although I'm sure it could affect something. I think the problem is in the way of defining again in Clients.js the Switch with the new Route and the Redirect

Comment: If you want those sub routes defined inside the clients component, you have to take off that exact or the clients component will unmount.  What is the reasoning behind requiring sub routes to be defined inside the component?? They can easily be defined inside the App instead and work the same way, even easier.

Comment: Can you help me with an example?